# Use Watson with Nao

Tags: python, ibm-watson, nao-robot, choregraphe

I want to use Watson service Speech to Text on Nao robot, but i have some dificulties with importing of watson developer cloud. I have impotred it, but every time I launch the script, there is an error that there is not a module. I have imported alredy some modules, but I have always new errors. Here is the code of imorting modules

```
memory = ALProxy("ALMemory")
filePath = memory.getData("fileName")

try:
import watson_developer_cloud, pysorl,urllib3, ssl, openSSL
except:
behaviorPath = 
os.path.abspath(ALFrameManager.getBehaviorPath(self.behaviorId))
packagePath=os.path.dirname(behaviorPath)
libPath=os.path.join(packagePath,'lib')
sys.path.append(libPath)


import json

from watson_developer_cloud.speech_to_text_v1 import SpeechToTextV1
```

Now I have this error

```
SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not availale
```

But I imported ssl. 
All code works fine in Eclipse, but in Choregraphe it doesn't work.

Could you help me to understand what the probleme is?

Comment: Check with Python version is the Nao robot using. The Watson Python SDK works with Python > 2.7.9. I think Nao uses 2.7.4.

Comment: Is it giving you the SSL error from the robot, or from the simulator?  I only get this error from the simulator.

Comment: Full stacktrace would be helpful to check which part of your code produces the error.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46588528/1167890