# Installing a module on Choregraphe

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I am trying to install a python module to use in Choregraphe. For windows this does not appear to be an issue. All I have to do is make sure that the module is installed in Python on the operating system.

For OSX, it does not appear to recognise the module. I have also tried importing it as a folder to a project, but it still can't see it.

Comment: I don't think Choregraphe supports mac.

Comment: It supports Mac.

Comment: Simon you are right. There is a link for mac. https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/us-en/downloads/pepper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you try playing with the python system path: the location when he looks for library.

Like that (in your choregraphe box):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("path containing your_module folder")
import your_module
```

Comment: That worked for it to recognise my library, but it doesn't recognise any others it references. I tried adding them as well to the project. Now it recognises my library even if it is not in the project.

Comment: Choregraphe runs its own python, so it would make sense that libraries that are not specifically imported there are not available. Also, the path you use should be in the choregraphe project otherwise the robot will not see it (if it's located on your computer).

Comment: Some extra info can be found here: https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/forum/importing-python-modules-pypi-my-choregraphe-project-3171

Comment: Thanks. The link gave better details, and I was able to resolve it from that! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [linked site](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/forum/importing-python-modules-pypi-my-choregraphe-project-3171):

1. Download python scripts of Requests and its dependencies from github.

2. Copy these scripts into my Project content(I made 'lib' directory in the project and copied all scripts into the folder)

3. Add the following code to import the modules

```
import sys, os
framemanager = ALProxy("ALFrameManager")
folderName = os.path.join(framemanager.getBehaviorPath(self.behaviorId), "../lib")
if folderName not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(folderName)
import requests
```

4. Add the following to unload the modules

```
import sys
if self.folderName and folderName in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(folderName)
```